# Get the attribute from CSS selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm trying to access the `sender` attribute of an XML document:

```
<adi:ADI2 createDateTime="2015-04-10T15:36:03+02:00" docNumber="777"
  sender="test" relativePriority="1"...
```

with the following command:

```
xml.css('/adi|ADI2[sender]')
```

But it doesn't work, it gives the exact same result as:

```
xml.css('/adi|ADI2')
```

To get the value of the attribute, I'm forced to use:

```
xml.css('/adi|ADI2[sender]').attribute('sender')
```

Is there a way of getting the attribute directly from the CSS selector?

Comment: We'd like to see a more complete example of your XML. Having the name space declaration helps us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a document root and name-space declaration in your XML sample but here's a simple example of what to do:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML('<root xmlns:adi="http://foo.com"><adi:ADI2 createDateTime="2015-04-10T15:36:03+02:00" docNumber="777" sender="test" relativePriority="1"><root>')
doc.at('adi|ADI2')['sender'] # => "test"
```

Once we have a pointer to a [Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node), it can be treated much like a hash. From the [Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) documentation:

> A Nokogiri::XML::Node may be treated similarly to a hash with regard to attributes.

```
irb(main):004:0> node
=> <a href="#foo" id="link">link</a>
irb(main):005:0> node['href']
=> "#foo"
irb(main):006:0> node.keys
=> ["href", "id"]
irb(main):007:0> node.values
=> ["#foo", "link"]
irb(main):008:0> node['class'] = 'green'
=> "green"
irb(main):009:0> node
=> <a href="#foo" id="link" class="green">link</a>
irb(main):010:0>
```

Your syntax using

```
xml.css('/adi|ADI2[sender]')
```

is incorrect.

`/adi|ADI2[sender]` is an attempt to use mixed CSS/XPath selector it looks like. I'd recommend sticking to CSS as it's simpler and easier to read, unless you need the power of XPath.

Also, instead of using [`css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:css), you might want to use [`at`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:at). [`css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:css) returns a [NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet), and you can't return the specific attribute of every [Node](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node) found using the `[attr]` syntax unless you iterate over the [NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet) using `map`. If you'll have multiple instances of that tag, then [`css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:css), [`xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:xpath) or the generic [`search`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:search) will work, otherwise use [`at`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:at), or the language-specific [`at_css`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#at_css-instance_method) or [`at_xpath`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:at_xpath), to find the first such occurrence. `at` is equivalent to `search('...').first`.

Nokogiri's "[Searching an HTML / XML Document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces)" tutorial covers this.

Answer (score 1):

To get an attribute one could use `@` selector:

```
▶ xml = '<tag sender="test">'
#⇒ "<tag sender=\"test\">"
▶ xml = Nokogiri::XML(xml, nil, "UTF-8")
#⇒ #<Nokogiri::XML::Document:0x5ca6f16 name="document" children=...>
                 # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ attribute
▶ xml.xpath('//tag/@sender').text
#⇒ "test"
```

Comment: This is XPath, not a selector.

Comment: @BoltClock It selects an attribute. It is not _css selector_, that’s true.